# Use zsh completion in vim instead of vim one

Tags: vim, zsh, tab-completion

I like zsh completion where for example I can write <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and get `folder/other_folder/file.txt` (I'm not sure, it's possible feature of `oh-my-zsh`, not `zsh`, but it seems that it doesn't matter)

Also I like execute commands from vim using `:!comm and` and I want completion here too.

Can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581845/how-to-autocomplete-file-paths-in-vim-just-like-in-zsh)?

Comment: @romainl, oh, didn't think about searching SO.